# Annoying NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon, balloon-tip

Is it me, or something nasty going on here about `NotifyIcon`. Whatever I give to `timeout` parameter of `NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip` method it is shown for only certain amount of time. Which is around **9 secs** on win7 and win 8.1 and around **4 secs** on windows server 2008 r2. These are the operating systems I tried so far.

I tried both overloads of `NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip` but I get same results.

```
//this is only shown for 9 seconds
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(15000);
```

and this

```
//this is only shown for 9 seconds too :)
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(15000, "1 sec", "shown for one sec", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

On msdn it says:

> Minimum and maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds, respectively, however this can vary depending on the operating system.

Okay, but don't we have any word on this? If it is a preset value, why there is this `timeout` parameter?

I'm hoping I'm missing something stupid. (I'm working with .net 4.5)

Comment: If downvoters can steer me into the right direction I would be appreciated.

Comment: Go to this page [NOTIFYICONDATA structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It says clearly in `uTimeout`: ***Note**  This member is deprecated as of Windows Vista. Notification display times are now based on system accessibility settings...*

Comment: Annoying indeed. I wish they mentioned this in `ShowBalloonTip` methods msdn page too. Btw if you post an answer regarding to your comment I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε's comment, I made sure that I wasn't missing anything. And the next thing to do was creating a NotifyBalloon project, so I did it.

Fellow sufferers can check and use it from my public gitHub repository [NotifyBalloon](https://github.com/tolgaevcimen/NotifyBalloon).